# How to disable the redefinition of macros in c++config.h?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, config

This may be a stupid question. If I want to use the `std::vector` implementation with the `_GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION` defined as `1`, what should I do?

```
#define _GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION 1
#include <vector>
static_assert(_GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION); // error: static assertion failed
```

I [**tried**](https://godbolt.org/z/rb6aMqYT3) to pass the `-D_GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION` flag to gcc, but it did not work, since `<vector>` contains `c++config.h`, and `_GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION` is redefined to `0` in `c++config.h`.

Comment: What if you redefine it after including `config.h`?

Comment: Trying to change internal macros sounds really dangerous. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @chtz I want to use the [smaller version](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_bvector.h#L430) of `vector<bool>`, but it only enables when `_GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION` is defined as `1`.

Comment: @vahancho. Seems [doable](https://godbolt.org/z/5qE8M73K7), thanks!